# How to create a javascript function that calculates probability percentages in values from 0-99

Tags: javascript, html, function, probability, dice

in the following code, pretend the two broken images are each dice that show anything from 0-9. that means that when you add their values they could show anything from 0-99 making them 100 sided.

In the table you need to be able to input probability values that add up to 100 when you combine each column. the third and fourth column are supposed to show which rolls you would need to get to have those numbers appear. there are examples when you run the code.

I'm having trouble actually getting the chart to work how I want it to, can someone code a quick function for me? I will put credit in my comments for the code.

```html
<!--Daniel Woods-->
<!--CMPT 250 -->
<!-- Lab 4 -->
<!-- Nov 20, 2017-->

<doctype! html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="red" text="white">

<head>
<title>Wandering Monster Table</title>
</head>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Probablility Percentage</th>
    <th>Encounter</th> 
    <th>Minimum roll</th>
    <th>Maximum roll</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="prob1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="encounter1" value=""></td>
    <td>??</td>
    <td>??</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="prob2" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="encounter2" value=""></td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="prob3" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="encounter3" value=""></td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="prob4" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="encounter4" value=""></td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>99</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>  <!--Declares the possible variables-->
var side0=new Image()
side0.src="d10_0.png"
var side1=new Image()
side1.src="d10_1.png"
var side2=new Image()
side2.src="d10_2.png"
var side3=new Image()
side3.src="d10_3.png"
var side4=new Image()
side4.src="d10_4.png"
var side5=new Image()
side5.src="d10_5.png"
var side6=new Image()
side6.src="d10_6.png"
var side7=new Image()
side7.src="d10_7.png"
var side8=new Image()
side8.src="d10_8.png"
var side9=new Image()
side9.src="d10_9.png" 
</script>

<center>

<h1>Wandering monster table</h1>



<img src="d10_0.png" name="die1">
<img src="d10_0.png" name="die2">
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click here to roll" onClick="roll()">
</form>
</center>

<script>      <!--Randomly chooses a variable between 0 and 5-->
function roll(){
 
var random=Math.round(Math.random()*10)
document.images["die1"].src=eval("side"+random+".src")
var random2=Math.round(Math.random()*10)
document.images["die2"].src=eval("side"+random2+".src")
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question: I guess the minimum and maximum roll refers to the value of the dice after rolling? If that's the case, you can't possibly manually dictate the probability: for example, to get 25–29 you basically have a certain number of probability, that cannot be set by the user. Also, can the position of the dice be swapped? i.e. rolling 2 and 9 can mean 29 or 92 (permutation vs combination) p/s: If you're using simple string concatenation there is no need to use `eval`—it's dangerous, only use it when you know what you're doing